# Dynamic xor Matrix, Segment fault or time out

Tags: c, matrix, bit-manipulation

I'm doing [this exercise](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/xor-matrix) that builds a dynamic xor matrix:

I'm getting a segfault because of lack of memory:

```
int main() {
   long long int col,row;
   scanf("%lld %lld",&col,&row); 
   int **matrix = new int*[row]; 

   for(long long int i=0; i<row; i++)
     matrix[i] = new int[col];

     for(long long int k=0;k<row;k++)
     {
       for(long long int j=0;j<col;j++)
       {
         if(k==0)
         scanf("%d",&matrix[k][j]);
            else if(j!=(col-1))
 __asm__ ( "xorl %%ebx, %%eax;": "=a"(matrix[k][j]) : "a"(matrix[k-`1][j]), "b"(matrix[k-1][j+1]));`

            else if(j==(col-1)) 
 __asm__ ( "xorl %%ebx, %%eax;": "=a"(matrix[k][j]) : "a"  (matrix[k-1][j]), "b"(matrix[k-1][0]));
            //  matrix[k][j]=matrix[k-1][j]^matrix[k-1][0]; 
            if(k==(row-1))  
              printf("%d ",matrix[k][j]);                             
       }           
     }
   }
```

I tried to do it with 2 arrays without a double cycle but I got a CPU timeout.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: The fact that the number of rows can be up to 10^18 should tell you that you cannot do this in memory.  That implies there is a mathematical/logical solution instead.

Comment: You are right, but I don't know which is the matematical logical solution

Comment: Maybe you should begin by doing some figuring on paper and see what the pattern is.